# Characterize the equivalence class of bipartite graphs obtained from each other by elementary row operations on their adjacency matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Let $M$ be an $m\times n$ matrix real matrix. Let $G$ be a bipartite graph, with partitions $A$ and $B$, such that $|A|=m$ and $|B|=n$. A node $i\in A$ is linked to a node $j\in B$ if and only if $M_{ij} \ne 0$.

Consider the matrices $M'$ obtained from $M$ by elementary row operations, and $G'$ the corresponding graphs. Starting from a graph $G$, what sort of graphs $G'$ can we obtain?

Can you characterize the equivalence class of bipartite graphs obtained from each other by elementary row operations on their adjacency matrices?

Comment: What field are you working in?  Anyway I don't think you'll find anything more than what basic linear linear algebra gives.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay The field of real numbers. I added an edit.

Comment: @becko what kind of row operations do you have in mind? With a symmetric graph I would expect the same operation to be also applied to the corresponding colums.

Comment: It sounds like we are not talking about directed or multigraphs? Then the field should be $\mathbb{Z}_2$...anyway it is an interesting "type" of adjacency graph, not the usual as row index and column index always represent different vertices.

Comment: If the field is $\mathbb{Z}_2$, then performing a row operation $k \cdot$Row$_i$ doesn't make much sense, as $k$ can only be $1$. Exchanging rows is the same as re-indexing the vertices in partite set $A$, so eg exchanging row $i$ and $j$, is the same as changing the index of vertex $i$ to $j$ and vice-versa. And performing a row operation $k \cdot$Row$_i +$ Row$_j$ (again $k$ can only be 1) is the same as deleting an (existing) edge $jk$ whenever we have an edge $ik$, and adding an edge $jk$ when we have an edge $ik$ and $jk$ did not exist. From there I guess one can explore further...

Comment: @ChristiaanHattingh I am not using $\mathbb{Z}_2$, I am using real numbers. There's an edge between nodes $i,j$ iff $A_{ij}\ne 0$.

Comment: @ManfredWeis Only elementary row operations are allowed. No column operations. The row operations allowed are the usual ones used in Gaussian elimination.